# Why does Imagick turn the switch backgroundcolor?

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to convert an pdf to a jpeg, trim the whitespaces around the content and resize it to 300x600
In PHP using ImageMagick 6.7.7-10

here's my code:

```
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor("white");
$im->readimage($url);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->trimImage(0);
$im->resizeImage(300, 600, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9);
$im->writeImage($tmpFilePath);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

here is the PDF
http://cs1.fuman.de/file.php/1AOrL6-PzT71Z-dk0000-CsjquC
and here the resulting JPG
http://cs1.fuman.de/file.php/1AOrL0-kWAl8P-ml0000-xAhOiw

Does anyone know, what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance
JD

Comment: Try use `$im->setResolution(300,600);` instead `$im->resizeImage(300, 600, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9);`

Comment: This indeed handles the black background problem, but the resulting image is 223 x 421

Comment: Then change resolution to correct one :D

Comment: Well that's what I have done by using $im->setResolution(300,600);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the background color is being ignored. I think it's to do with JPEG not having a concept of a 'background' colour, and so when the image is converted from having alpha to not having alpha, bad things happen.

I suggest using this code:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();

// Make the image be large when read from PDF so have decent quality later
$imagick->setResolution(92, 92);

// only use the first page of the PDF
$imagick->readimage("./orig.pdf[0]");

// Make a white background imge
$canvas = new Imagick();
$canvas->newPseudoImage(
    $imagick->getImageWidth(),
    $imagick->getImageHeight(),
    'canvas:white'
);

// Need to use png format to keep alpha channge
$imagick->setImageFormat('png');

// Composite our image, into the white background
$canvas->compositeImage($imagick, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);
$canvas->resizeImage(300, 600, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$canvas->setImageFormat('png');
$canvas->writeImage("output.png");
```